# Why does this code raise a LNK2019 error?

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, lnk

I was just making sure I understood inheritance by building this simple program where Dog inherits from Mammal. I am getting an error when I compile it. All it should do is go into a constructor for mammal and dog, bark, then go into a destructor for mammal and dog. I apologize that the indentation came out a bit off in the post, it is well organized in Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Mammal
{
public:
    Mammal();
    Mammal(int age);
    Mammal(int age, int mammal);
    ~Mammal();
    int getAge() {return itsAge;};
    int getWeight() {return itsWeight;};
    void setAge(int x) {itsAge = x;};
    void setWeight(int x) {itsWeight = x;};
    void speak() {cout << "MAMMALALALALALLLL!" << endl;};

private:
    int itsAge, itsWeight;
};

class Dog : public Mammal
{
    public:
        Dog();
        Dog(int age);
        Dog(int age, int weight);
        Dog(int age, int weight, string breed);
        ~Dog();
        void setBreed(string breed) {itsBreed = breed;};
        string getBreed() {return itsBreed;};
        void bark() {cout << "Bark!" << endl;};
    private:
        string itsBreed;
};

Mammal::Mammal()
{
    cout << "Mammal constructor." << endl;
    setAge(0);
    setWeight(0);
}

Mammal::Mammal(int age)
{
    cout << "Mammel(int) constructor." << endl;
    setAge(age);
    setWeight(0);
}

Mammal::Mammal(int age, int weight)
{
    cout << "Mammal(int, int) constructor." << endl;
    setAge(age);
    setWeight(weight);
}

Mammal::~Mammal()
{
    cout << "Mammal deconstructor." << endl;
}

Dog::Dog():
Mammal()
{
    cout << "Dog constructor." << endl;
    setBreed("");
}

Dog::Dog(int age):
Mammal(age)
{
    cout << "Dog(int) constructor." << endl;
    setBreed("");
}

Dog::Dog(int age, int weight):
Mammal(age, weight)
{
    cout << "Dog(int, int) constructor." << endl;
    setBreed("");
}

Dog::Dog(int age, int weight, string breed):
Mammal(age, weight)
{
    cout << "Dog(int, int, string) constructor." << endl;
    setBreed(breed);
}


int main()
{
    Dog Goldie(5, 50, "Lab");
    Goldie.bark();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the compiler is as follows:

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Dog::~Dog(void)" (??1Dog@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\austin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Inheritance\Debug\Inheritance.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.31
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please post the full error-message you are getting.

Comment: maybe you could post the error it gives you ;) ?

Comment: Just posted the full log from the compiler, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

You declared a destructor for `Dog` class, but did not define it.
You should define it as well.

```
    Dog::~Dog(){}
```

Error on gcc, clearly tells that:

> prog.cpp:(.text+0xf54): undefined reference to Dog::~Dog()
>   prog.cpp:(.text+0xfc3): undefined reference to Dog::~Dog()

**[Working sample](http://www.ideone.com/blPcO)** of your code after the modification

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined the destructor for `Dog`:

```
Dog::~Dog()
{
    cout << "Dog destructor." << endl;
}
```